# How to select all rows of group if one row within group meets certain condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'a': ['cust1', 'cust1', 'cust1', 'cust2', 'cust2', 'cust3', 'cust3', 'cust4', 'cust4'],
                   'year': [2017, 2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019],
                   'cond': [True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True]})

       a  year   cond
0  cust1  2017   True
1  cust1  2018   True
2  cust1  2019  False
3  cust2  2018   True
4  cust2  2019   True
5  cust3  2017   True
6  cust3  2018   True
7  cust4  2018   True
8  cust4  2019   True
```

How do I select all rows of group in column 'a' where 'year' = 2019 has 'cond' = True?

resulting dataframe should look like this

```
       a  year   cond
3  cust2  2018   True
4  cust2  2019   True
7  cust4  2018   True
8  cust4  2019   True
```

Logic:

rows for group cust1 do not get selected as year 2019 = False

rows for group cust2 get selected as year 2019 = True

rows for group cust3 do not get selected as year 2019 no data available

rows for group cust4 get selected as year 2019 = True

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, [`boolean_indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) + [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas-series-isin)

```
print(
    df[df.a.isin(df.loc[df.year.eq(2019) & df.cond, 'a'].unique())]
)
```

---

```
       a  year  cond
3  cust2  2018  True
4  cust2  2019  True
7  cust4  2018  True
8  cust4  2019  True
```